# "errorMessage": "'httpMethod'", "errorType": "KeyError",

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Trying to PATCH data into DynamoDB, GET and POST work just fine. when it comes to PATCH I'm getting this error

```
{
    "errorMessage": "'path'",
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "requestId": "2d9d09ac-9450-45ab-bbbf-36a92188179c",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 22, in lambda_handler\n    path = event[\"path\"]\n"
    ]
}
```

my Lambda code for PATCH method. I detected the some methods so that the question will be shorter

```
import boto3
import json
from custom_encoder import CustomEncoder

dynamodbProductTable = "prod-status"
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
prodcutTable = dynamodb.Table(dynamodbProductTable)
patchMethod = "PATCH"
productPath = "/product"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    httpMethod = event["httpMethod"]
    path = event["path"]
    if httpMethod == patchMethod and path == productPath:
        requestBody = json.loads(event["body"])
        response = modifyProduct(requestBody["productId"], requestBody["updateKey"], requestBody["updateValue"])
    else:
        response = buildResponse(404, "Not Found")
    
    return response 

def modifyProduct(productId, updateKey, updateValue):
    try:
        response = prodcutTable.update_item(
            Key={
                "productId": productId
            },

            UpdateExpression="set {0}s = :value".format(updateKey),
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ":value": updateValue
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
        body = {
            "Operation": "UPDATE",
            "Message": "SUCCESS",
            "UpdatedAttributes": response
        }
        return buildResponse(200, body)
    except:
        logger.exception("error in modifyProduct")

def buildResponse(statusCode, body=None):
    response = {
        "statusCode": statusCode,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
    }

    if body is not None:
        response["body"] = json.dumps(body, cls=CustomEncoder)
    return response
```

I'm using a custom encoder for decimal numbers, since decimals are not supported for default JSONEncoder
Custom Encoder code

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal 

class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

I think the error is because of the body of the event so this is the body i been sending [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLNPM.png)

I am still new to AWS and trying different projects to get hand-on experience. I got stuck with this for days, I changed the code and tested still no change, just got it worse till the point I had to recreate the entire thing. Thank you ,I really appreciate it for your Time.

Comment: `KeyError` usually means you are trying to read something that doesn't exist in the dictionary. Probably has nothing to do with Dynamo. I'd start by looking at `path = event["path"]`

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that `path` does not exist in the `event` dict. An easy way to overcome your issue is to do the following:

```
print(json.dumps(event))
path = event.get("path")
```

This will allow you to fetch for path in a safe way, and you also print the event to be sure you have the correct path for `path` in your dict.